# How to get cloud build to connect to docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, google-cloud-build

I have a maven project I build using GCP cloud build. It works just fine but I want to add integration tests to it. The way I run integration tests on my dev machine is I start docker compose which launches a server container and the tests talk to it using http://localhost:8080. Again that works fine.

Now, when I try to combine these approaches and run the integration tests under Cloud Build I run into problems. The docker compose part seems to work just fine according to the Cloud Build logs. But then my integration test runs it fails to connect to the server. Specifically I see a `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException`. To make sure it wasn't something more complicated I replaced the integration test with a `curl` command. Same error.

I don't know why it doesn't connect in this case. It seems to be the same situation as my dev machine talking to localhost. I did find [this reference](https://threedots.tech/post/running-integration-tests-on-google-cloud-build/) to specifying the the `cloudbuild` network by adding this to a file docker-compose-ci.yml:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cloudbuild
```

Then I invoke docker compose in my Cloud Build with two files `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose-ci.yml` which allows me to keep the `cloudbuild` separate for local testing

But sadly I still get the same error.
This is my `cloudbuild.yaml` and my `docker-compose.yml` files. I have replaced the maven build with a curl statement and my test server in docker compose with an echo server. I still get the same problem with those changes, but it shows it isn't just a programming error on my client or server 'cos they aren't part of it for this example. The error message changes slightly because the client isn't Java but it looks like the same problem: `connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused`

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >
        gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet --verbosity=debug `echo
        ${_CONTAINER_REPO} | cut -d / -f 1`
    id: gcloud auth
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: 
      - "compose"
      - '-f'
      - 'snakecharmer-web/docker/docker-compose2.yml'
      - '-f'
      - 'snakecharmer-web/docker/docker-compose-ci.yml'
      - 'up'
      - '-d'
    id: docker-compose
  - name: 'appropriate/curl'
    args:
      - "-v"
      - "http://localhost:8080/param?query/demo"
    id: build
    waitFor: [docker-compose]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: 
      - "compose"
      - '-f'
      - 'snakecharmer-web/docker/docker-compose2.yml'
      - '-f'
      - 'snakecharmer-web/docker/docker-compose-ci.yml'
      - 'down'
    id: docker-compose-down
    waitFor: [build]
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  echo:
    image: ealen/echo-server
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. Well I looked at [this post](https://blog.yongweilun.me/running-tests-with-docker-compose-on-cloud-build) and that pointed the way. The bit I was missing was that the build is running on the same network as docker compose. So the server should not be addressed as `localhost` but as the name of the service. In this case `echo`.